# How to make server react separately on click-event sent from different clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm writing a Tic-tac-toe game, which allows playing a game between 2 users in different browsers, using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript (ES6), Node.js with express und socket.io modules.

Each click of the Client provides a field number (0 to 8) which is then used by server to call the move-method and make the move to that field.

The problem is I need to make server respond differently to a click-event form both clients and I cannot figure out how to make it happen.

To make it clearer move-method uses 2 arguments - symbol("X" or "O") and field (0 to 8), so basically who clicked and where.

The Clients get their assigned symbol on connection, so when each of them then click one field, server calls a move-method, that uses Client's assigned symbol and field-number that it becomes from the client as arguments.

But how do I make two separate server responses to the clicks from different clients, given that each connected client's socket is pushed to an array Clients, so the first client is clients[0] and the second is clients[1]

Here is part of the server code:

```
    let clients = [];

    io.on("connection", socket => {
    clients.push(socket);

    if (clients.length === 1) {
      io.emit("message", "Please wait for your Opponent!");
    };

    if (clients.length === 2) {
      io.emit("message", "Two players are connected. The game can start now!");

    io.to(clients[0]).emit("symbolMessage", `You play as ${player}.`);

    io.to(clients[1]).emit("symbolMessage", `You play as ${nextPlayer}.`);

    io.emit("turnMessage", `Next move by: ${player}`);
    };


    socket.on("myClick", (data) => {
      myGame.move(player, data);
    });

    socket.on("myClick", (data) => {
      myGame.move(nextPlayer, data)
    });
```

And a relevant part of the client side code:

```
    const field = $$("td");

    field.on("click", event => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const fieldNumber = id.match(/\d/g).join("");
    console.log(fieldNumber);
    socket.emit("myClick", fieldNumber);
    });
```

Comment: Code format fixed

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which client a socket even is coming from? or how to send an event to one client in particular?

Comment: Couldn't you just send a player number along with the data and handle it depending on which player sent the data?